# Shortcut to open specific bookmark / URL in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, bookmarks

How to enable keyboard shortcut to open specific bookmark / URL while using Chrome?

Comment: Firefox users interested in this feature can set [keywords](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Using_keyword_searches) for bookmarks, which can also be used to create custom searches.

Comment: I totally vote for implementing the keyword feature from Firefox into Chrome. Each bookmark can have a single key to be triggered (that's how I am using it). This saved me hundreds of hours of typing. Really a pity that Chrome 51 is still not providing this feature by core.

Comment: An extension called [AutoControl Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocontrol/lkaihdpfpifdlgoapbfocpmekbokmcfd) lets you assign shortcuts to specific bookmarks, bookmark folders and URLs.

Comment: If you are already using  Vimium, you can press b and any letter from your bookmarks to open it.

Comment: It should be noted that AutoControl Shortcut Manager is Windows-only.

Comment: You can now search your bookmarks natively in Chrome: https://blog.google/products/chrome/search-your-tabs-bookmarks-and-history-in-the-chrome-address-bar/

Answer (score 65, accepted):

#### Without extensions

The only ways (that I know of) to open a bookmark with the keyboard are the following:

- Using the **Bookmark Manager**:

  1. Open **Bookmark Manager** by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.
  2. Three options:

     - Search all bookmarks (just start typing), press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice and select the desired bookmark with the arrow keys.
     - Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, select the desired folder, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again and select the desired bookmark with the arrow keys.
     - If the desired bookmark is in the Bookmarks Bar, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice and select the desired bookmark with the arrow keys.
  3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Using **Customize and control Google Chrome**:

  1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to open **Customize and control Google Chrome**.
  2. Press <kbd>B</kbd> to enter **Bookmarks**.
  3. Assuming the desired bookmark is in the **Bookmarks Bar**, select it with the arrow keys.
  4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Using the **Omnibox**:

  1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>F6</kbd> to focus the **Omnibox**.
  2. Type (part of) the desired bookmark's name.
  3. When it appears in the drop-down below the **Omnibox**, select the desired bookmark with the arrow keys.
  4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

#### With extensions

Several extensions are able to do this. The easiest way is probably a user script like this one:

```
// ===UserScript===
// @name          Bookmark Launcher
// @description   Launches bookmarks with keyboard shortcuts
// ===/UserScript===

var bookmarkLauncherSetup = (function() {
    var bookmarks = {}, url;

    bookmarks['G'] = 'http://google.com';
    bookmarks['S'] = 'http://superuser.com';

    window.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
        if(event.ctrlKey && event.altKey && !event.shiftKey)
            if(url = bookmarks[String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)])
                window.open(url);
    });
}());
```

To use it, do the following:

1. Modify the array `bookmarks` to suit your needs. All letter and number keys should work fine.
2. Save the code as `bookmark-launcher.user.js` in a location of your choice.
3. Open `chrome://extensions/` in Google Chrome.
4. Drag and drop `bookmark-launcher.user.js` in the open tab.
5. Click **Add**.

Note that no extension can function in tabs opening `chrome://...` URLs (this includes **New Tab**) or the **Chrome Web Store**.

In any other tab (after reloading it), pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> will open [Super User](http://superuser.com) in a new tab.

Note that you have to be focusing the tab itself. If you're focusing, e.g., the omnibox or the developer console, the keyboard shortcuts won't have any effect.

Comment: The userscript can't work on some pages (http://github.com for example), since they don't accept script-injection...

Comment: **Update** fixed the problem with script-injection, edited the answer. Should work now...

Comment: I have tried adding a `js` file by dragging over the `chrome://extensions` window but the file cannot be dropped there, the cursor changes to a blocked icon. I appreciate this answer is quite old but can anyone confirm that this is still possible with current versions? I am on `52.0.2743.116 m`

Comment: @tallpaul it looks like now you need to package it as an extension, with `manifest.json` file, to add it.

Comment: The OP asked for `Shortcut`, the stuff listed above is no shortcut. A shortcut is e. g. `CTRL SHIFT G` to open Google Mail etc.

Comment: @KaiNoack A *shortcut* is a faster way to achieve something and can very well involve several commands. In any case, the *with extensions* part of my answer requires only a single key combo to open the specified website.

Comment: Seems like a highly outdated version sadly. After writing manifest files and everything, which is now a requirement, it still does not work.

Comment: @Dennis Thank you for your work. Based on this answer, I created an extension that works again: https://superuser.com/a/1313997/276470

Answer (score 32):

As reported in [How to Assign a Keyboard Shortcut Key to Frequently Used Google Chrome Bookmarks](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/add-shortcut-keys-chrome-bookmarks/) the key is to set the specific URL to a default Search engine.

1. Open `chrome://settings/searchEngines` to load the list of search engines.
2. In "Other search engines" add a new one with the following parameters:

   - **Search engine**: the name you give to the search engine.
   - **Keyword**: the keyword you want, say SU.
   - **URL with %s in place of query**: `http://superuser.com/` alone if you want the alias to point directly to the site.

After saving it, whenever you type `SU` in your URL bar you will be either sent to `http://superuser.com/` or to `http://superuser.com/bla`.

> [image]

You can also specify a placeholder `%s` when filling the *URL with %s in place of query* field, say `http://superuser.com/%s`. Then, when you type "su" <kbd>Tab</kbd> + "bla" it will send you to `http://superuser.com/bla`.

This is the current behaviour for Google Chroome 79.

Comment: love this idea, https://gist.github.com/Artistan/45fa744b899f4f054173693298d41930

Comment: One can also rightclick the url bar and select "edit search engines" instead of having to remember the chrome: url

Comment: In 2020 you're going to have to type a space and a "search phrase" as well -- Enter won't work. That's fine, your URL won't have a %s in it, so any letter will work. For example just type `SU s`.

Comment: This stopped working after the first time I tried it, I think because Google figured out it was a static site with no search variable. I put a dummy `%s` in the URL, like `http://superuser.com/#%s`, and that seems to keep it working.

Comment: @Noumenon thanks for your comment. Using Chroome 79 it worked to me without any placeholder. I updated the answer, feel free to indicate your version if the behaviour I explain is not the same in your version.

Comment: I'm on 79 too. If it's not the same for everyone, I honestly think you're better off reverting the edit and leaving the pristine, simple answer. Explaining how %s works takes away from the lightbulb moment of "Hey, I could add a keyword search without a keyword!" If it doesn't work for them, then my comment would be there for a workaround.

Answer (score 21):

Another approach is to

- Move focus to the url bar with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
- Type the full name of the bookmark followed by a <kbd>/</kbd>.
- Press <kbd>tab</kbd> to select the second autocompletion (which in my experience is always the first matching bookmark name).
- Press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: `Type the full name of the bookmark` is not a shortcut, sorry.

Comment: @KaiNoack I just tried it on Chrome on Linux. It doesn't actually require the full name, partial is enough (with possibly more tab auto-complete usage)

Comment: Typing enough characters to be unique is enough, if you prefix your bookmark names with the desired shortcut keys this can be kept very short. (Unfortunately it doesn't substring match anywhere in the name, you have to type from the left)

Comment: This doesn't work any more, unless there's a way to turn Google search recommendations off. Even "bxzyz" would need seven tab presses.

Comment: This method is really good. It even works with js bookmarklet. Very handy. Just put a short prefix as the desired shortcut in front of the name of your bookmark.

Answer (score 11):

*Note: Shortcut is defined as 1 key combination, most of the other answers do require more typing.*

**Solution A: AutoHotkey for Windows**

Use the [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) scripting language for Microsoft Windows and define your own shortcuts for your main bookmarks. This requires using an application to support that language. Here is a script that I prepared as a dummy for you: [chrome-bookmarks-shortcuts.ahk](https://github.com/q2apro/ahk-snippets/blob/master/chrome-bookmarks-shortcuts.ahk)

For instance, hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>WIN</kbd> and hit <kbd>G</kbd> to open gmail.com.

---

**Solution B: Chrome extension**: [SiteLauncher (Speed Dial)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sitelauncher-speed-dial/calhgleedaaigmhnoklfenlfhlbfdloo)

It helps to a certain extent.
However:

- you can only assign **one letter** to a bookmark, not two or more.
- this requires installing proprietary software (its code cannot be audited).
- it feels a bit buggy.

---

**Solution C: Chrome extension:** [Shortkeys (Custom Keyboard Shortcuts)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck/related?hl=en)

This extension can handle one letter or combinations to open assigned bookmarks.
Warnings:

- You cannot enter those combinations in the address bar. My workaround: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> for new tab, then <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> then combination.
- This extension feels a bit buggy.

---

**Solution D: Using Chrome's "Custom SearchEngine" (Hack)**

This solution does not need any plugin or extra software: https://superuser.com/a/468548/169199

---

**Shortcuts in Firefox**

To recall how the bookmark properties look like in Firefox and how easily you can assign a [keyword (shortcut)](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Using_keyword_searches) to it:

[image: Firefox keyword field]

In Firefox, now entering "mp" in the address bar opened the specific website. As you can read in the net, Chrome does not have this simple feature and uses the "Search engine" section for this.

Answer (score 10):

0. First make sure your bookmarks bar is showing (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>)
1. Focus on the bookmarks bar. The shortcut for that depends on your environment and focus. On Microsoft **Windows**, either <kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> should do it.
2. Use arrow keys (if needed) to reach the desired bookmark. Usually the right arrow.
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Details on step 1: Those combinations switch focus between the Address bar, Bookmarks bar (if showing), and page content. So if my focus is on the page content, I would use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and then use my arrow keys to navigate my bookmarks.

Comment: For firefox without using keywords?

Comment: thank you for the good solution!  how about on Mac OS?

Answer (score 7):

Inspired by the approach of Dennis:

It didn't work for me and this is probably because his answer is kind of old, but I liked the approach about implementing this myself, since there doesn't seem to be a proper solution out there in the web store.

Here's what you need to do:

- Create 2 files, `manifest.json` and `background.js`. Put them into a new folder and add the content below to those files.
- Within chrome, type `chrome://extensions` in the address bar and activate developer mode on the top right (switch).
- Click on the `Load unpacked` button that appeared and select your folder containing the files.

That's it, with this, you have what you need. As soon as you type CTRL+ALT+G, google will open in a new tab. :)

**manifest.json:**

```
  {
    "name": "Bookmark Shortcutter",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Custom shortcuts for bookmarks! Coolio!",

    "permissions": ["http://*/*", "tabs"],
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["background.js"],
        "run_at": "document_start"
      }
      ],
    "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

**background.js:**

```
if (window == top) {
    window.addEventListener('keyup', doKeyPress, false);
}

var bookmarks = {}, url;

bookmarks['G'] = 'http://google.com';
bookmarks['S'] = 'http://superuser.com';

function doKeyPress(event){
    if(event.ctrlKey && event.altKey && !event.shiftKey) {
        if(url = bookmarks[String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)]) {
            window.open(url);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like an amazing solution, but when I press "Load Unpacked" no dialog comes up. I think it doesn't work when the page says "Your browser is managed by your organization." You still deserve an upvote.

Comment: worked for me, right of the bat :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this chrome extention [Shortkeys (Custom Keyboard Shortcuts)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck) provided by Mike Crittenden.

[image: shortcut]

Comment: Works beautifully for my bookmarklet. Though I had to use `Run Javascript` instead of `Open Bookmark/Bookmarklet`. And it supports Mac `Cmd` modifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Addition to the top answer's solution, if you want to also use some scripts like changing playback speed on youtube:

```js
var bookmarkLauncherSetup = (function() {
    var bookmarks = {}, url;
    bookmarks['G'] = 'http://google.com';
    bookmarks['1'] = 'javascript:document.getElementsByClassName("video-stream html5-main-video")[0].playbackRate = 1';
    bookmarks['2'] = 'javascript:document.getElementsByClassName("video-stream html5-main-video")[0].playbackRate = 1.5';
    bookmarks['3'] = 'javascript:document.getElementsByClassName("video-stream html5-main-video")[0].playbackRate = 2';
    bookmarks['4'] = 'javascript:document.getElementsByClassName("video-stream html5-main-video")[0].playbackRate = 2.5';
    bookmarks['5'] = 'javascript:document.getElementsByClassName("video-stream html5-main-video")[0].playbackRate = 3';
    bookmarks['6'] = 'javascript:document.getElementsByClassName("video-stream html5-main-video")[0].playbackRate = 4';
    bookmarks['7'] = 'javascript:document.getElementsByClassName("video-stream html5-main-video")[0].playbackRate = 5';

    window.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
        if(event.ctrlKey && event.altKey && !event.shiftKey) {
            if(url = bookmarks[String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)]) {
                try {
                    eval(url);
                } catch {
                    window.open(url);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works by typing a keyword into the address bar (omnibar) and pressing enter to jump to a specific url.
In Chrome (as of version 59.0), this isn't available through the bookmark manager like it is in Firefox, but you can easily use the Search Engine Shortcuts feature of Chrome to work the same way.

1. Right click the address bar (omnibar)
2. Select edit search engines...
3. Click on 'ADD' - which appears after the default search engines section
4. In the dialog that pops up:

   - in the **search-engine** field - name your bookmark
   - in the **keyword** field - enter your keyword shortcut string (what you will need to type in the omnibar to quickly jump to this 'bookmark'
   - In **URL** field - type in the url you want to associate with the keyword

Note: the url can contain a special placeholder: "%s" (without the quotes) that will serve as a placeholder for additional text that you can enter if you press tab after typing the keyword shortcut.

**For example:** 
I use a keyword shortcut that jumps to list of bookmarks on pinboard.com by given tag. For that:

- I use 'pint' as keyword,
- and https://pinboard.in/u:jaysen/t:%s/ as url.

Then to access all my bookmarks on pinboard tagged with 'todo'

- I type 'pint' in omnibar,
- press TAB
- type the tag I want to visit - in this example 'todo'
- and ENTER
  This takes me to https://pinboard.in/u:jaysen/t:todo/

Answer (score 1):

An easily accessible fuzzy search over your Chrome bookmarks:

1. In order to search the bookmarks, activate [Vimium chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en)'s "Vomnibar" with `b` key from any webpage.
2. If you want to create a system-wide shortcut, you could use the following [Autohotkey automation tool](https://www.autohotkey.com/) script

   ```
   #NoEnv
   SetBatchLines -1
   ListLines Off
   SendMode Input

   #Space::  ; windows+space will open a Chrome window with search bar over bookmarks from any location
   run, http://blank.org  ; Or any regular webpage. A local webpage would work as well.
   WinWait ahk_exe chrome.exe
   WinActivate ahk_exe chrome.exe
   WinWaitActive ahk_exe chrome.exe
   send, {b}
   return
   ```

Bonus: [you can search your bookmarks by folder](https://github.com/philc/vimium/wiki/Tips-and-Tricks) by using `/`. Type in "Vomnibar" `/myBookmarkDir myBookmark`

Answer (score 0):

Using the code and instructions of [Chrome Bookmark Shortcut](https://github.com/iSunilSV/Chrome-Bookmark-Shortcut) you can now diminish the number of keypresses required to open predefined sites.

You need to manually edit the javascript code and create a dummy bookmark, but instructions are provided in the repository above.

Comment: what does this do?

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is quite old. But this is to inform those interested by a solution, that in the past weeks I have programmed an extension to mimic firefox behavior.

The extension picks the aliases directly from your bookmarks. The user adds an alias by editing a bookmark in chrome's bookmark manager. If it works as a bookmark it works as an alias (http(s), javascript, with/without %s parameter). It's also easier to export/import bookmarks with their aliases.

You can find it in the webstore under the name "Alias Bookmarks" by Achernar.

Comment: Update:
I have since added aliased folders to the extension. It is still experimental, but you can use it to do a "group search" with a set of search engines (with parameters).
Feel free to test.

Answer (score 0):

### December 2019.

If you arrived here looking for **what Google Chrome calls now shortcuts** (differing from keyboard shortcuts) because you want to add shortcuts to specific URLs in your Windows 10, this might help.

> Make sure your Windows 10 is updated to the latest version (1903).

#### Create shortcut manually

Most flexible option.

> In order to add multiple shortcuts to the same domain **you need to create them manually. COPY-PASTE doesn't work**.

1. Open your file explorer and go to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Chrome Apps`
2. `Right click > New > Shortcut`
3. The **location of the item** is:  `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome_proxy.exe"  --profile-directory=Default --app="`**TARGET_URL**`"`
   .

   - Replace **TARGET_URL** with your relevant URL
   - Note that the path to chrome_proxy.exe might differ in your installation.
4. Now the shortcut is created but doesn't look pretty. You can change this by opening the `shortcut properties > Change icon…` and finding the relevant icon. **Tip:** If you created a shortcut from your browser before, the icon will be somewhere.
5. `Right click on icon > pin to start`. You can have multiple shortcuts to the same app, as long as the URL is somehow different.

#### Create shortcut using Chrome options

To then modify it to open a specific URL rather than the landing page.

1. Create the shortcut from Chrome: `"⋮" > More tools > Create shortcut…`
2. Go to `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Chrome Apps`
3. Right click the shortcut you created
4. In the Target field, replace `--app-id=XXXXXX` for `--app="`**TARGET_URL**`"`

   - Replace **TARGET_URL** with your relevant URL