# How can I bookmark a page to a folder with my keyboard in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

When I press Ctrl-d on chrome, I get the pretty bookmarked dialog. From there, I can click on "Add to folder" button and use my keyboard to choose the folder I want to place the bookmark in. However, I hate using the mouse, even for that initial click.

**How can I bookmark the page I am currently on to a specific folder without using the mouse at all? Is there a plugin that helps with this?**

Additionally, is there a plugin or something that allows me to choose the folder faster? I try to keep my bookmarks very organized and it would be awesome if there was something that allowed me to press ^d and then start typing a folder name (from any level of my bookmarks) immediately, without having to navigate through my bookmark hierarchy. I am already using vimium, but it does not seem to help at all with this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shortcut to open specific bookmark / URL in Chrome](http://superuser.com/questions/496212/shortcut-to-open-specific-bookmark-url-in-chrome)

Comment: I am trying to bookmark the current page, NOT open a bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

To open a bookmark with the keyboard are the following:

- Using the **Bookmark Manager**:

  1. Open **Bookmark Manager** by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.
  2. Three options:

     - Search all bookmarks (just start typing), press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice and select the desired bookmark with the arrow keys.
     - Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, select the desired folder, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again and select the desired bookmark with the arrow keys.
     - If the desired bookmark is in the Bookmarks Bar, press <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice and select the desired bookmark with the arrow keys.
  3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Using **Customize and control Google Chrome**:

  1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to open **Customize and control Google Chrome**.
  2. Press <kbd>B</kbd> to enter **Bookmarks**.
  3. Assuming the desired bookmark is in the **Bookmarks Bar**, select it with the arrow keys.
  4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This is the [source](https://superuser.com/a/496242/416314).

Comment: This is to open a bookmark, I am trying to bookmark the page I am currently on.

Answer (score 0):

Press "Ctrl+d" to open the bookmark dialog

Press "tab" to move to the folder field

Press the up/ down direction keys to navigate through your available folders.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I just tried this on two computers and tab doesn't navigate to the folder field for me. I am on Chrome 42.0.2311.68 beta and 42.0.2311.90, can't tab to the "Add to Folder" button on either one.