# Keyboard shortcut to open a bookmark?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, bookmarks

How can I set a keyboard shortcut to open a bookmark form the bookmark bar in Google Chrome or any other web browser?

Is it possible or not?

[image: see this image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shortcut to open specific bookmark / URL in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/496212/shortcut-to-open-specific-bookmark-url-in-chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it with extensions, you can try - 
[Bookmarks Hotkey Shortcuts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmarks-hotkey-shortcut/hfjofdnkkjjpjmkjmidfacfnfkmceoll?hl=en)

If you do not wish to use extensions, you may try this suggestion - 
https://superuser.com/a/1144653/1007503

...or try broader options listed in the same page - 
[Shortcut to open specific bookmark / URL in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/496212/shortcut-to-open-specific-bookmark-url-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

**Chrome**:

I love **lightweight** reliable extensions that do **no more and no less**.
Hence, I use the popular [bookmark-search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-search/hhmokalkpaiacdofbcddkogifepbaijk) extension. As the name suggests, it helps you quickly search for and go to your bookmarked sites (without using your mouse!)

To use it:

- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to focus on your search-bar, and then type `bm` followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd> to activate bookmark-search.
- Now start typing the name of your bookmark and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go to the link.

Personally, I became a lot more productive on Chrome once I started searching for my bookmarks this way.

Some other -- heavyweight -- options are listed here : [Shortcut to open specific bookmark / URL in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/496212/shortcut-to-open-specific-bookmark-url-in-chrome)