# Open URL in Google Chrome using a keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

Is there a way to open different URL´s with keyboard shortcuts?

Example:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> opens `www.google.com`
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> opens `www.fifa.com`, etc.

Comment: Similar, maybe good enough for you: https://superuser.com/questions/468547/how-can-i-create-a-url-shortcut-in-chrome

Comment: maybe a duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/496212/261198