# How can I set a keyboard shortcut for accessing Chrome's settings?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I know that settings can be accessed via the url `chrome://chrome/settings/`.But keyboard shortcut will be useful.

Comment: Mentioning or tagging the OS will be very helpful for the people to answer your query.

Comment: @avirk: Added now

Comment: You can also create a bookmark or a [URL shortcut](http://superuser.com/questions/468547/how-can-i-create-a-url-shortcut-in-chrome) to `chrome://chrome/settings/` to access it quickly.

Comment: @amiregelz: You could hotkey it up using https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-toolbox-by-google/fjccknnhdnkbanjilpjddjhmkghmachn

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can select it with the menu shortcut. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> will open the Chrome menu and then from there <kbd>s</kbd> will open Settings.

Comment: This doesn't work on full screen mode though...

Comment: @Metafaniel: https://superuser.com/a/1086653/861081

Comment: this does not work for me is this because another program is overriding this shortcut perhaps? or has something changed since 2012?

Answer (score 11):

There are actually three methods:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> then press <kbd>S</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> then press <kbd>S</kbd>
- <kbd>F10</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then press <kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: This doesn't work on full screen mode sadly...

Comment: wonder how does F and E combination also work

Answer (score 6):

Use the clear browser cache shortcut key then escape

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> then <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: Awesome this works in full screen mode too. +1

Comment: This is the best answer. It even works in kiosk mode, which none of the other methods I've tried did.

Answer (score 2):

Default shortcut on mac chrome is <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>. There should be same or about same on other systems

Comment: I think this one is Mac only, it doesn't exists on Windows

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it within Chrome as they have not provide any shortcut for this in my knowledge (anyone can correct me if I'm wrong). You have to download the [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com) and then install it on your system, now copy the following script and paste it on notepad and save it with extension `.ahk` where you can access it easily, now when you launch the Chrome just launch it with that.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, RegEx

#IfWinActive, - Google Chrome$

^M::
            ControlFocus, Chrome_OmniboxView1


Send chrome://chrome/settings/{Enter}

return
```

Now when you will press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> then it will open the setting page for your Chrome. You can bind other key instead of  <kbd>M</kbd>, you have to just repalce it with your desired one. Also If you want to use it with <kbd>Alt</kbd> key then replace the key <kbd>^</kbd> with <kbd>!</kbd>.

**Edit**: Also take a look at the [Shortcut Manger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortcut-manager/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf/) plugin for Chrome.

Comment: See the edits, maybe it can help you more.

Comment: from chrome 32 the ControlFocus's `ClassNN` no longer works, but the macro can be easily changed to `^M:::Send !es` as @Karl suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ferro to open the settings page and other pages, including "chrome://extensions", using only your keyboard. Alt-Shift-F, start typing the name of the chrome page you want (eg "settings"), and hit enter once what you want is the top suggestion.

[Ferro: the keyboard interface to Chrome](http://www.getferro.com)