# Is there a way to define how Chrome's search bar immediately recognizes initial letters in a search?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create a URL shortcut in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/468547/how-can-i-create-a-url-shortcut-in-chrome)

Example: When I type "m", immediately, "mail.google.com" fills out, so I can just do 'm' followed by 'enter' to go to gmail.

Similar things happen with t (twitter) among many others.

In some cases, though, I want to define specifically the first choice - in particular, for "c". When I type "c", I get chase.com, but I would prefer to get "https://www.google.com/calendar/render" so I could go to my calendar quickly.

I'm sure that Google uses an algorithm to rank what to put first - hence putting "mail.google.com" first for "m" since I go there often - so I thought maybe by going to calendar more the effect might happen, but it hasn't.

Just wondering if there are shortcuts for this. Thanks for any advice.

(PS. I am aware of editing search engines so you can do, for example, "d" followed by a space and then whatever you want to immediately search on dictionary.com, but that is a separate feature.)

Comment: I do not believe this is possible, at least without using an extension. If you don't want a separate feature though, I believe the only way to accomplish this is to edit the Chromium Source itself. You could make yourself your own browser. A lot of work just for that though.

Comment: (Just an Idea) To achieve similar functionality I use **Autohotkey** Hotstring feature. When I type `su` followed by space it expands to superuser.com.

Comment: Do you know you can [take advantage of the custom search engines feature in Google Chrome to create simple URL shortcuts?](http://superuser.com/a/468548/138020) You don't have to use that feature for searching inside a website.

Comment: I found a nice solution here: http://superuser.com/questions/468547/how-can-i-create-a-url-shortcut-in-chrome/468548#468548 (thanks to a comment by @amiregelz)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike IE’s old `SearchUrl` key which *required* a parameter to use a custom search-engine (e.g., for your example, you would have type `c blah` or `c .` or something in the address-bar), Chrome’s custom search-engines don’t *require* you to add the `%s` parameter at all:

1. Right-click the Omnibar
2. Select *Edit search engines…*
3. Click *Add*
4. Enter `Calendar` in the *Name* field
5. Enter `c` in the *Keyword* field
6. Enter `https://www.google.com/calendar/render` in the *URL* field
7. Click *OK* and *Close*
8. Click the Omnibar
9. Press <kbd>c</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>
10. Marvel at your new shortcut
11. Wonder about making a bunch more…

Answer (score -1):

(A workaround) With a simple [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) script you can have **exactly the same functionality**.

After installing AutoHotKey, create new `.ahk` file with following code. Run it.
Now typing `m` followed by `enter` or `space`, will take you to gmail automatically.

```
::m::mail.google.com
::ahk::autohotkey.com   
::su::superuser.com
```

These are known as **HotStrings**, you can modify them according to your need. 
The script can be made context sensetive so that these HotStrings are activated only in Chrome.