# Point fake TLD to real website in browser

Tags: google-chrome, redirection, url

There is a website which I visit a lot for some purpose, and I often visit it by typing the URL into the navigation bar manually, because I know where all the documents are. However, the URL is very long, and I would like to have a shortcut for it in my browser.

I can't just do this in my hosts file, since the URL has many subdomains. I want to be able to type in something like `http://e/my/page.html` in the bar and go to `http://example.com/my/page.html`, but I also want something like `http://subdomain.e/thing` to go to `http://subdomain.example.com/thing`, for any subdomain of example.com. I am gambling here that `.e` is never going to be a valid TLD, of course, but suppose I have found one I am okay with losing. Either a redirect or a hosts-file-like DNS override will do, I just want to be able to type the shorter in the browser, and for it to know I mean to go to the longer one.

Is such a redirection possible? I am okay with browser-specific solutions, but I prefer the latest version of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If a Chrome specific solution is acceptable, you could try the solution provided by amiregelz to a prior Super User question, [How can I create a URL shortcut in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/468547/how-can-i-create-a-url-shortcut-in-chrome)

Comment: I need to distinguish subdomains as well: if there is a way to make Chrome search engines understand multiple arguments, I would be interested in hearing it.

Comment: @algorithmshark, I believe you can use a bookmarklet in the Chrome search engines. You could write one to expand whatever you type into the correct URL.